# Header for frontmatters using scrpage2

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, front-matter, scrpage2

How to set page numbers for front matters similar to main matters. Main matters header need to have chapter title also. Not added in MWE. Front matters must have only page number as in main matters of MWE.

```
%
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\chapter{First}
\section{Introduction}
Text

\section{Some Examples}
Text

\subsection{Sections}
Text

\clearpage
\subsection{Tables and Figures}
Text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scrplain` pagestyle for `\frontmatter`, and switch to `scrheadings` for `\mainmatter`. Optionally, redefine the `\chapterpagestyle` command at `\mainmatter`. If you want the first pages of frontmatter *and* mainmatter chapters to show no header/footer at all, add `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\ihead{\leftmark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{scrplain}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% optional

\chapter{First}
\section{Introduction}
Text

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}% just for the example

\section{Some Examples}
Text

\subsection{Sections}
Text

\clearpage
\subsection{Tables and Figures}
Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to remove page number in chapter title page.

Comment: @sandu In that case one may need more than two page styles. To be sure: How exactly should the first page of frontmatter chapters (e.g., the ToC) look like, and how the first page of main matter chapters?

Comment: The first page of frontmatter chapters (e.g., the ToC)  and the first page of main matter chapters both look similar. No header or footer in the first page of chapter.

Comment: @sandu I'll assume they should be empty (without page number *and* without chapter title).

Comment: yes   they should be empty.